# Mount nfs to container with docker compose

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, nfs

Does anyone know how to mount an NFS to a docker container using docker compose? I keep getting the same error each time I run 'docker compose up':

```
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_data/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /etc/hapee-2.2/certs:/var/lib/docker/volumes/test_data/_data, data: addr=10.15.50.27,nolock,soft: invalid argument
```

Exports file from the NFS appears to be set up correctly. I've tried deleting '/home/' from the file path as well. IP address is redacted.

```
/etc/hapee-2.2/certs <ipaddressofpc>(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

I keep suspecting the docker-compose.yml, but I'm not sure what the issue with it would be

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  hapee:
    image: haproxy:2.2
    container_name: test
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - data:/etc/hapee-2.2/certs
    logging:
      options:
         max-size: 100m
         max-file: "3"

volumes:
  data:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=10.15.50.27,nolock,soft,ro"
      device: "/etc/hapee-2.2/certs"
```

Alternatively, does anyone know another method of mounting SSL certificates to an HA Proxy container with docker compose?

Thanks!

Comment: Added the yml text instead of the image. Thanks for the heads up, all!

Comment: Some googling suggests the problem could be a missing `nfsvers` in your mount options. Can you try adding `nfsvers=3` or `nfsvers=4`, depending on which version you're running, and check if that works? See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/825652/mount-nfs-an-incorrect-mount-option-was-specified

Comment: Just tried adding it to the 'o:'. Did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example copy pasted directly:

```yaml
volumes:
  barril-immich-upload:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=10.0.0.10,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/volume1/immich/upload"
  barril-immich:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=10.0.0.10,nolock,soft,rw"
      device: ":/volume1/immich"
```

I hope it helps.